# Ability to change the attributes of the default selector when uploading through android

Tags: android, web, responsive

We have a website where on mobile and specifically android devices when people want to change their "avatar" image the options that show up when we click on "upload" does not have the "Gallery". Instead it has "Documents" is there a way to define what to show and what not to show?

We are using PHP if that matters at all for development.

Please see below image.

[image: After clicking browse to change avatar image]

Answer (score 1):

well it depends on which intent you have used for upload button, in my opinion the most appropriate intent to call when you want user to select an image would be

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

it would make the gallery and other photo handling apps visible in the chooser dialog.

for more information you can go [here](http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/)

Hope it helps